# grid(tetris) inventory system

Tags: unity, c#, grid, logic

I'm trying to adapt my current inventory so that the items can occupy more than one slots (cells) like in this image:

[image]

Any idea that might help me? My inventory is an Image that has grid layout and inside it, there's other images (which represents the slots), and each slot has the object "Image" inside which is the sprite of the item:

[image]

Items:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Item", menuName = "Create new Item")]
[System.Serializable]
public class Items : ScriptableObject
{
    public int id;
    public string itemName;
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Sprite icon;
    public int maxStack = 1;
}
```

I tried to define in class item an `line` `height` and a `list` of type `sprite` in my `icon` but don't know how it would fit with the rest of the code.

`ItemObject` is a class that represents the object instantiated in the game:

```
public class ItemObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Items itemStats;
    public int amount;
}
```

Slot the behaviour of each individual slot and when I try to drag an item into it:

```
public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
    public Items ItemInSlot;
    public int AmountInSlot =1;
    Image icon;
    Image panel;
    TextMeshProUGUI txt_amount;

    public void SetStats()
    {
        transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);

        icon = GetComponentInChildren<Image>();
        panel = icon.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();
        txt_amount = panel.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();

        if (ItemInSlot == null)
        {
           transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
            return;
        }

        icon.sprite = ItemInSlot.icon ;
        txt_amount.text = $"{AmountInSlot}x";
    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        GameObject dropped = eventData.pointerDrag; // image being dragged
        InventoryUIInteraction draggableItem = dropped.GetComponent<InventoryUIInteraction>();
        Slot slot = draggableItem.draggedItemParent.GetComponent<Slot>();

        if (slot == this)
            return;

        if (ItemInSlot != null && ItemInSlot.id != slot.ItemInSlot.id)
            return;

        if (ItemInSlot)
        {
            if (ItemInSlot.maxStack == AmountInSlot)
                return;

            if (ItemInSlot.maxStack < (AmountInSlot + slot.AmountInSlot))
            {
                int remainingAmount = (AmountInSlot + slot.AmountInSlot) - ItemInSlot.maxStack;
                AmountInSlot = ItemInSlot.maxStack;
                slot.AmountInSlot = remainingAmount;
                SetStats();
            }
            else
            {
                AmountInSlot += slot.AmountInSlot;
                slot.ItemInSlot = null;
                slot.AmountInSlot = 0;
                SetStats();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ItemInSlot = slot.ItemInSlot;
            AmountInSlot = slot.AmountInSlot;

            slot.ItemInSlot = null;
            slot.AmountInSlot = 0;
            SetStats();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Inventory class that handles the logic of an item being picked and placing it:

```
public class InventorySystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public Slot[] slots = new Slot[40];
    [SerializeField] GameObject InventoryUI;

    private void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (slots[i].ItemInSlot == null)
            {
                slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!InventoryUI.activeInHierarchy && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            InventoryUI.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (InventoryUI.activeInHierarchy && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            InventoryUI.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    
    public void PickUpItem(ItemObject obj)
    {
        int remainingAmount = obj.amount;

        // Check if the item can be stacked in existing slots or added to empty slots
        for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (slots[i].ItemInSlot != null)
            {
                if (slots[i].ItemInSlot.id == obj.itemStats.id && slots[i].AmountInSlot < slots[i].ItemInSlot.maxStack)
                {
                    int remainingSpace = slots[i].ItemInSlot.maxStack - slots[i].AmountInSlot;
                    int amountToAdd = Mathf.Min(remainingAmount, remainingSpace);
                    slots[i].AmountInSlot += amountToAdd;
                    remainingAmount -= amountToAdd;
                    slots[i].SetStats();

                    if (remainingAmount == 0)
                    {
                        // All items have been added to existing slots
                        Destroy(obj.gameObject);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                slots[i].ItemInSlot = obj.itemStats;
                slots[i].AmountInSlot = Mathf.Min(remainingAmount, slots[i].ItemInSlot.maxStack);
                remainingAmount -= slots[i].AmountInSlot;
                slots[i].SetStats();

                if (remainingAmount == 0)
                {
                    // All items have been added to empty slots
                    Destroy(obj.gameObject);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        // If there are still remaining items, they don't fit in the inventory
        obj.amount = remainingAmount;
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be extremally helpful.

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? A good representation of the shape? (Can it be L-shaped?). Or some way of checking whether it fits when placing?

Comment: how to properly thinnk which steps I should do, like checking whether it fits

Comment: Where / how do you represent the size & shape of the inventory items?

Comment: in the Item Class I put the row and columns it occupies